# Wordpress body_class(). How to set the right class for my index?

Tags: wordpress

I customised my theme where the index.php works as a "page". But with `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` it's create the class "blog", which I don't want to. I want to change the class name to "index" or "home. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/body_class) function accepts several parameters. The classes are restricted to the defaults listed, but I think you could [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/body_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters) it in your theme's function.php file and let "body" out.

After checking out [the source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post-template.php), I'm not really sure if you can leave it out. It's sort of hard-coded, you should filter get_body_class() maybe (if possible).

Check the link to read more about it.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the link.
I know you can write your own function at functions.php and replace the original one. But I would like to use a filter and stick with the original. But it's seem that is not possible to do it. :-)